# Embed hyperlink and add bold to email generated in access

Tags: function, email, ms-access, hyperlink

I am using the DoCmd.SendObject function to send an email in access I would like the message to be able to embed a hyperlink and bold certain sections so that it appears as follows:

Dear Recipient,

**Here is some text that is bold.**

Here is a link to [Google](http://google.com).

```
DoCmd.SendObject acSendNoObject, "NotNeeded", acFormatXLS, strCEMEmail, , , "Subject Line", "Dear Recipient," & vbCrLf & vbCrLf "Here is some text that is bold." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf "Here is a link to Google."
```

Comment: I'm not sure you can format the body using this function. Luckily, [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197046.aspx) includes an example of how to go about constructing the message in a way that will allow you to format the body of the message. See the third example `SendEmailWithOutlook`.

After the `.Body = MessageBody` line, you can use the [.BodyFormat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869979.aspx) property to use either RTF or HTML to format the body the way you request.

Comment: Thanks for the other option. I'm new to access and am having trouble understanding how to convert my existing DoCmd function to the one provided by MSDN. Where within the third example on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197046.aspx) would I type my message with the HTML?

Comment: You can replace `MessageBody` with `"Dear Recipient"` etc, but it also will not be formatted. To format, you will need to understand how to make text bold and make hyperlinks in either HTML or RTF, which would require the use of `.BodyFormat` property. Unfortunately, I do not know either, or I would provide an answer. There should be examples of tutorials on google that may provide some insight on how to go about solving that part. Sorry I can't be better help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add HTML tags to your email body. 
If you are using Outlook have a look at this link for an example of the syntax https://access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=229533